# mysql error1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax,Error of insert statement in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I did adding user_name to mysql but it has a syntax error, please help me, thanks a lot

```
c = db.cursor()
insert = "INSERT INTO db_viewdata(user_name) VALUES(%s)"
val = (profile)
c.execute(insert,val)
print("ok")
db.commit()
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: try `val = (profile,)`

Comment: you can use `f-string` here `f"INSERT INTO db_viewdata(user_name) VALUES({profile})"` then `c.execute(insert)`

Comment: What value is `profile`?

Comment: @MZ If that were the issue, it wouldn't be a syntax error, would it?

Comment: @JohnGordon I thought it might be the cause – not for a python syntax error but a MySQL syntax error. that being said there was no harm in suggesting a tuple for that scenario